# Failed to load config "react-app" to extend from. Referenced from:<path>\.eslintrc

Tags: react-admin

I have installed the react-admin and I face problems to get it to run.

I ran this npm install react-admin successfully and when I run make install at the root it fails with this message:

MAKE Version 5.2  Copyright (c) 1987, 1998 Inprise Corp.
Fatal makefile 152: No terminator specified for in-line file operator

When I run npm start then I get this :

Failed to load config "react-app" to extend from. Referenced from:.eslintrc

Any help with this is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you find answer pls let me know.

Comment: For the 2nd error, have a look here: https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/13283